# FieldError: Unknown field(s) (created_at, modified_at) specified for Account

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to create a timestamp for my model `Account`, but I don't want my two time stamps (`created_at` and `modified_at`) to be editable or even viewable by the user. Everything works fine and as expected until I add `editable=False` to the `created_at` and `modified_at` fields. Here is my model:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    account_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, editable=False)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, editable=False)

    def save(self):
        if self.id:
            self.modified_at = datetime.datetime.now()
        else:
            self.created_at = datetime.datetime.now()
        super(Account, self).save()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('id',)
```

Here is the obscure error I get when I try to do anything (migrate, runserver, etc):

`django.core.exception.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (created_at, modified_at) specified for Account`

As soon as I remove `editable=False` from both fields, everything works fine. Is this a Django bug? Is there a better way to make the field non-viewable and non-editable by the user?

I am using Django 1.9 and Python 3.6.1. Thanks for the help, let me know if you need me to post anything else (views, serializers, etc).

**EDIT**

Full traceback: https://pastebin.com/YEQACX5z

Accounts Form:

```
class AccountForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ['account_name', 'active', 'created_at', 'modified_at']
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: Added full traceback.

Comment: The traceback shows that the error is occurring in your `AccountForm`, which you haven't shown.

Comment: Hmm okay, I added my AccountForm as well.

Comment: Django doesn't let you include fields with `editable=False` to your model form. You should either remove `editable=False` or remove them from the model form.

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just do,

```
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and

```
modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**From the docs**,

> DateField.auto_now¶
>
> Automatically set the field to now every time the object is saved. Useful for “last-modified” timestamps. Note that the current date is always used; **it’s not just a default value that you can override**.
>
> The field is only automatically updated when calling Model.save(). The field isn’t updated when making updates to other fields in other ways such as QuerySet.update(), though you can specify a custom value for the field in an update like that.
>
> DateField.auto_now_add¶
>
> Automatically set the field to now when the object is first created. Useful for creation of timestamps. Note that the current date is always used; **it’s not just a default value that you can override**. So even if you set a value for this field when creating the object, it will be ignored.

**So, no need to add editable=False, its already non-editable.**

Also, remember to remove your `save()` method override since it's trying to modify those fields.

If you want to be able to modify this field, set the following instead of auto_now_add=True:

```
For DateField: default=date.today - from datetime.date.today()
For DateTimeField: default=timezone.now - from django.utils.timezone.now()
```

The default form widget for this field is a TextInput. The admin adds a JavaScript calendar, and a shortcut for “Today”. Includes an additional invalid_date error message key.

Comment: Both of these draw the same error as when I add editable=False: `django.core.exception.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (created_at, modified_at) specified for Account`

Comment: @Logicman make sure you remove your `save()` method override.

Comment: Hope you got what you were looking for!

Comment: `auto_add_now` and `auto_add` sound like exactly what I want. However I am now getting the error: `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyowrd argument 'auto_add'`. Any ideas?

Comment: sorry, its not **auto_add** that was my mistake, its **auto_now**... I'll edit the answer now..

Comment: Thank you, this is a much better way of doing it, rather than overriding the save function. I had to delete both `created_at` and `modified_at` from my AccountForm as well for this to work, which I think was my original issue with `editable=False`.